# SQL Query for When Then and Count

Tags: mysql, sql, ssms

I have a table

```
ID |Code   |Start      |End
1  | SKX007| 2020-06-01|2020-06-11
2  | SRP120| 2020-05-01|2020-05-01
3  | SKX454| 2020-05-01|2020-06-21
4  | SKX471| 2020-06-11|2020-06-15
```

Im trying to get where i print the first 3 letter of the code and the count of it start or end in jun.

```
Code |"Count Code in June"
SKX  |  3
```

Currently i have this

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
      WHEN Code LIKE 'SKX%'
          THEN 'SKX'

      WHEN Code LIKE 'SRP%'
          THEN 'SRP'
    END AS 'Start Code'

SELECT COUNT(Code) AS "Count Code in June" from Loan
    WHERE MONTH(Start) = 6 or MONTH(End) = 6;
```

How do i merge this 2 statement together?

Comment: Are your start and end columns really three letter month abbreviations, or do they actually store complete dates?

Comment: they are in complete date format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to merge your statements is

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE 
      WHEN Code LIKE 'SKX%'
          THEN 'SKX'

      WHEN Code LIKE 'SRP%'
          THEN 'SRP'
    END ) AS "Count Code in June", CASE 
      WHEN Code LIKE 'SKX%'
          THEN 'SKX'

      WHEN Code LIKE 'SRP%'
          THEN 'SRP'
    END AS 'Start Code' from Loan
    WHERE MONTH(Start) = 6 or MONTH(End) = 6
group by CASE 
      WHEN Code LIKE 'SKX%'
          THEN 'SKX'

      WHEN Code LIKE 'SRP%'
          THEN 'SRP'
    END
```

Comment: where can i insert the having statement if i only want to display if count is more than 2?

Answer (score 0):

> Im trying to get where i print the first 3 letter of the code and the count of it start or end in jun.

I would suggest:

```
select left(code, 3) as code_3, count(*)
from loan
where month(start) = 6 or month(end) = 6
group by code_3;
```

Note:  It is very, very rare to want the month without the year.  If you want June 2020, then you would want:

```
select left(code, 3) as code_3, count(*)
from loan
where (start >= '2020-06-01' and start < '2020-07-01') or
      (end >= '2020-06-01' and end < '2020-07-01')
group by code_3;
```

And then this would not include rows that are *active* in June but start before and end after.  So you may really want any overlap:

```
select left(code, 3) as code_3, count(*)
from loan
where start < '2020-07-01' and
      end >= '2020-06-01'
group by code_3;
```